# How do environment variables in web applications get resolved?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, netlify

I have a website hosted on Netlify where I set certain environment variables in the build & deploy tab. To access them in my React application I can do the following:

```
const someId = process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_ID;
const otherId = process.env.REACT_APP_OTHER_ID;
```

But how does `process.env` get its values? Is it an object in the global context or do they somehow get resovled in real-time? If not, how does using environment variables make it harder for an attacker to get sensitive data? They could simply call `process.env.<whatever>` in the console to get all data.

At what point do these variables receive their values? Could that even depend on the host?

Comment: this is done by bundler (by webpack, for example). webpack replaces process.env.* with corresponding values. so at runtime you have exact inlined values instead of process.env expressions

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: It makes it no harder for an attacker to get sensitive data. Anything that's actually secret must **not** be exposed to the client app.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov Meaning that in the end the values are visible in the application as plain text? So it is actually the equivalent of using the `environment` object in Angular (in case you're familiar with that)? EDIT: thanks for your link, it clarifies all my doubts. Thanks!